# "type is missing the following properties from another type" when assign values with expected data shape in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to assign a set of values for a const with specific interface, but for some reason, even the data shape is the same, I am kept getting error of `type is missing the properties`

[image: error]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show OrderItemInterface definition?

Comment: @EvgenyKlimenchenko yes! Sorry just added, totally forgot

Comment: Answered you question, hope it actually solves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `[]` at the end because it is an array of `OrderItemInterface`, but in your definition you say that the type is an object with structure of `OrderItemInterface`, but it is an array that contains object with structure `OrderItemInterface` so should be like this:

```
const currentCart: OrderItemInterface[] = SimpleCardWithQty1;
```